# Should I define all my variables in the module.settings.yml file?

Tags: 8, configuration

With the new Configuration Management System we can create a module.settings.yml file with all the variables that we will use in our module.

Now just to made a test I delete all the content inside my module.settings.yml file (leaving the file empty), I reinstalled the module and it works, so I deleted my module.settings.yml file and I reinstalled my module one more time and, the module works, I can set the variables (the configuration is created) and I can use the variables, even I can export the configuration.

In this scenario I see that you don't need to define your variables even the file is not needed (or maybe I missing something). So, should I define all my variables in the module.settings.yml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talking of the configuration file in config/install, [its purpose is setting the default values for the configuration used from the module](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/config_api/8.2.x#sec_yaml).

Deleting its content could probably not make much difference if the default values are `FALSE`, `NULL`, or an empty string. In the other cases, its content would make a difference.

Comment: In my case is a string array, and the module works perfect without having the file the config/install directory.

Comment: Ohh I just read this again and I note that you says: "its purpose is setting the default values for the configuration used from the module" I thought that his function is to define the variables that will be used by the module. Can you provide me some references about this?

Comment: I found here https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/configuration-storage-in-drupal-8 this: "An extension (module, theme, or profile) that provides default values for its configuration must put that configuration into YAML files in its config/install sub-directory." So, is not mandatory to define the settings.yml file?

Comment: I was referring to what reported in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/config_api/8.2.x. As far as I can say, it is not mandatory. The configuration schema is something highly recommended, though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't need it if your variables are optional. If you have required variables or if you just want to provide default variables put it in a module.settings.yml file within a config/install folder.

Comment: I use the variables to save module configurations, so the first time I install the module I don't need the variables.

Answer (score 0):

## Drupal Docs update

In Drupal Docs there is an explanation of how to configuration, Structure, get and edit `module_name.settings` file in `config/install` subdirectory of your module directory as here:  [Defining and using your own configuration in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/defining-and-using-your-own-configuration-in-drupal-8) as follow:

The simplest way to use this is the `Drupal::config()` static method:

```
$config = \Drupal::config('example.settings');
// Will print 'Hello'.
print $config->get('message');
// Will print 'en'.
print $config->get('langcode');
```

If you want to edit a configuration and update it with a new value you can use the `\Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable()` method:

```
$config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('example.settings');

// Set and save new message value.
$config->set('message', 'Hi')->save();

// Now will print 'Hi'.
print $config->get('message');
```

To know more please read it. The best part it explains how to make your settings translatable using `langcode` key and including two more files `example.schema.yml` and `example.config_translation.yml`.